# Why does Terminal swallow Ctrl+up/down keystrokes?

Tags: keyboard, snow-leopard, terminal, iterm

In Terminal.app on Snow Leopard, the key combinations <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> don't get passed through correctly. Instead Terminal.app receives a single <kbd>↑</kbd> or <kbd>↓</kbd> key stroke.

I have verified this by running `cat -v`, which prints the code `^[[A` for both <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>↑</kbd>, and the code `^[[B` for both <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> and <kbd>↓</kbd>.

I have looked through the keyboard shortcut settings in System Preferences, but nothing is mapped to them. Furthermore, the keystrokes work in MacVim (I first noticed this issue when these keystrokes didn't work for me in vim in the terminal).

I'm also running iTerm2, which doesn't receive <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> at all (as tested with `cat -v`).

Where can I figure out what's eating my <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> keystrokes in Terminal.app and iTerm2?

Comment: There is no ASCII code for Ctrl-Up/Ctrl-Down, any software who wants to interpret Ctrl-Up different from Up must check the status of any modifier key itself. `cat` obviously doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Terminal preferences, go to Settings and select Keyboard in the panel. There you can set various key combinations to send whatever string you wish to the shell (or the program currently running).

Comment: I see, this needs to be set manually? Is there a reason why this key combination (or any not listed in the preferences) are not sent through to the Terminal?

Comment: What makes you think this key combination is not sent through to the Terminal? If you can set it in the Terminal preferences, and it then works, then it is sent through. It's just that Terminal in its default configuration chooses to ignore it. Yes, it needs to be set manually, most likely because there is no well defined standard as to what should be sent in response to these keypresses.

Comment: Right, I should have instead asked why Terminal chooses to ignore the key combination if it's not defined in the preferences. Lack of a well defined standard seems plausible. Thank you!